# Prime Printer using js?

Tags: javascript

Hello we were given a task where a user inputs any value up to 200 only and if it's a prime, it should print prime and if not, not prime. I already changed the code precisely. However, it's not working. Why is it so?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<script>
  function doAction(){

    //gets the value from the text field with id input1 and stores it in variable num1
    var num1 = document.getElementById("input1").value;



    //HINT: loop through some finite number and check whether they are prime
    //You can create a function out of the CheckPrime exercise and use that to check if a number is 
Prime

    //for loop the numbers until you satisfy the num1

    function primeprinter(num1) {
  for(var i = 2; i < num1; i++)
    if(num1 % i === 0) return false;
  return num1 > 1;

  if (primeprinter === true){
      <p> Prime </p>
  }
  else{
      <p> Not Prime </p>
   }
}





    //Challenges:
    //validate if the input are numbers. Hint: Check out isNaN() function
    //Validate the input to only be less than equal 200
  }


</script>

<h2>Prime Numbers Printer</h2>
Prints the first N prime numbers. Only try up to 200.
<br/>
<br/>
Input1: <input type="text" id="input1"/>
<button type="button" onclick="doAction()">
Print Prime</button>
<br/>
<br/>
Result:
<p id="output"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

I am a beginner at javascript. Please help me ;-;

Comment: You can't inline HTML in JavaScript, e.g. `if (primeprinter === true){ <p> Prime </p> } else { <p> Not Prime </p> }` doesn't work. Either you use a templating framework like [Handlebars](https://handlebarsjs.com/) or you manipulate the DOM by hand.

Comment: how huhu please give the answer and give an explanation i cnt still graps ;-;

Answer (score 0):

You can't inline HTML in JavaScript, i.e. `if (primeprinter === true){ <p> Prime </p> } else { <p> Not Prime </p> }` doesn't work. You could manipulate the DOM by hand.

```js
function primeprinter(num1) {
  for (let i = 2; i < num1; i++)
    if (num1 % i === 0) return false;
  return num1 > 1;
}

function doAction() {
  const num1 = document.getElementById("input1").value;
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = primeprinter(num1) ? "Prime" : "Not Prime";
}
```

```html
<h2>Prime Numbers Printer</h2>
<span>Prints the first N prime numbers. Only try up to 200.</span>
<br />
<br />
<label for="input1">Input1: </label><input type="text" id="input1" />
<button type="button" onclick="doAction()">Print Prime</button>
<br />
<br />
<span>Result:</span>
<p id="output"></p>
```

Comment: @blank Yes, you can run it directly by pressing "Run code snippet" and see how it works.

Comment: @blank It works for me. I press on "Run code snippet". A web site opens. I enter 23, press the button and get `Prime`. I enter 22, press the button and get `Not Prime`. What happens when you press on "Run code snippet"?